# Post params from client ignored in Controller's Action (always null)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

Having this in `Index.cshtml`

```
  <form asp-controller="Authentication" asp-action="Test" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="titi" value="titi-val" />
    <input type="text" name="toto" value="val-toto" />
    <button type="submit">Test Submit</button>
  </form>
```

this

[image]

this in the `AuthenticationController.cs`

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/authentication")]
public class AuthenticationController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(string toto, string titi) {
        logger.LogInformation($"Test '{toto}', '{titi}'");
        return Ok(toto+titi);
    }
```

I get this:
[image]

> The titi field is required

and

> The toto field is required

> {"errors":{"titi":["The titi field is required."],"toto":["The toto field is required."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1" , "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-5a...03-00"}

PS.

Observed that this would work as expected

```
<form asp-controller="Authentication"
    asp-action="Test"
    asp-route-titi="titi-val"
    asp-route-toto="val-toto"
    method="post">
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API controllers does not process "simple" values from form by default. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#binding-source-parameter-inference-1):

> `[FromForm]` is inferred for action parameters of type `IFormFile` and `IFormFileCollection`. It's not inferred for any simple or user-defined types.

You need either to post data in some other way (json body mapped to some model or via query string parameters) or add `FromForm` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([FromForm] string toto, [FromForm] string titi)
{
    return Ok(toto + titi);
}
```

Comment: however, in the .net 5 application it works without `FromForm`, I mean, I migrate an old .net5 to a new .net7

Comment: @Putin-TheHero don't have .NET 5 installed by possibly there are some breaking changes for `ApiController`s from that version.